# Create columns in sheet2 depending on number of rows in sheet1 in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create columns in sheet2 depending on number of rows in sheet1 in excel.
e.g. 
i have data in sheet1

```
ROW1:rowvalue1
ROW2:rowvalue2
ROW3:rowvalue3
```

i would like to have it in sheet2 as

```
column1       column2      column3
rowvalue1     rowvalue2    rowvalue3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use copy & paste special 'transpose' - you can do this manually.

If you want to use VBA:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheets(1).Activate 'open the first sheet
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select  'select all values in column
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select   'this is where your data will be pasted
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True  'transpose=true flips your data around

End Sub
```

Where sheets(1) refers to the first sheet and sheets(2) to the second you can replace these with the index or name of your sheet (if you use name, use inverted commas around it), and I'm assuming your data starts in A1, the code:

```
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

selects all of the data to the last cell in that column.

To make this work over multiple columns, if they are all in a row, you can just transpose the whole block. eg:
    Sub Macro1()

```
    Sheets(1).Activate 'open the first sheet
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:X" & Sheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select  'select all values in column
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select   'this is where your data will be pasted
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True  'transpose=true flips your data around

End Sub
```

If you only want to do some columns rows, then you'll need to create a loop over the original code.

```
Sub Macro1()
    y = Array(1, 3, 5, 9) 'this is the index of columns A,C,E,F
    For x = 0 To 3
    Sheets(1).Activate 'open the first sheet
    RowCount = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, y(x)).End(xlUp), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, y(x)).End(xlUp)).Row
    Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, y(x)), Cells(RowCount, y(x))).Select 'select all values in column
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(2).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x + 1, 1), Cells(x + 1, 1)).Select 'this is where your data will be pasted
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True  'transpose=true flips your data around
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rowan,Thanks for quick reply. Your solution works perfectly for the given condition. 
But I have multiple columns in sheet1. 
column1   column2 column3
value1    1        4
val2      2        5
val3      3        6

will be converted to
value1   val2   val3
1         2     3
4         5     6

How can I modify above script to add this change?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
Sub PerformAction()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = 1 To LastRow
     Sheet2.Cells(1, i).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```